# GeoLocation fetching wrong latitude longitude

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am trying to fetch the current location using the geolocation . A month before it was giving correct location but not am getting different location . I have used the same code as below.

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    /*x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
    */  var query = "?latitude="+position.coords.latitude+"&longitude="+position.coords.longitude;
    var stateObj = { query: query };
    history.pushState(stateObj, "query added", query);
    var flag = true;
/*var req = (window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
req.onreadystatechange=function(){if((r.readyState==4)&&(r.status==200)){ console.log('location was sended to server'); }};
req.open("GET","?latitude="+position.coords.latitude+"&longitude="+position.coords.longitude,true);
req.send(null);
*/


}
```

Another problem is its fetching the latlong based on isp not on IP. So if i use this code using mobile internet ! It gives latlong of another state. Is there any way to make this work again?

Comment: what does `position.coords.accuracy` give you ?

Comment: some integer values..11106

Comment: is your real position within a 11 106m radius of the position it give you ? Also, on mobile, what navigator do you use and do you have the gps activated ?

Comment: Yes but while a month ago it was giving my exact position..

Comment: did you change browser or moved to an other geographical location ? It is also possible your ISP change that for privacy reason.

Comment: no everything is still the same... Haven't used that code for month